# I would like to get an Access Token to report state to HomeGraph

Tags: jwt, actions-on-google

I'm trying to implement the report state.
Sync, Query and Execute work well.
I am developing in vb.net and obviously I am struggling to find information and examples.

If I understand correctly, I must first request an Access Token for the Homegraph API and then send the new device status with POST.

The example in nodejs works but I have to get the same thing in vb.net.

In particular, it is not clear to me how to sign the JWT with only the private key relating to the service account.

Comment: Have you visited https://jwt.io/?

Comment: Dear Nick, yes i do.  I try to use System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.

Comment: I think this  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account is the correct documentation. With RS256 i need public key to sign the token but i don't know where is.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Finally i have get the access token succesfully with:
- i have build JWT with JWT.IO
- i have sign the JWT with Service Account Private Key
- i have sent JWT with Postman
Fundamental details (where i was wrong):
- Into JWT Payload, the claims IAT and EXP are numbers, in Unix Timestamp format (GMT+0)
- The Private Key found into JSON File contains some "\n", they must be removed before paste in JWT.IO page.
- The correct endpoint to obtain the access token is https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token .
Now i will go ahead with vb.net and System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.
See you.